# Loading pages using AJAX database connection error and pages path problem

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

When i use AJAX to load php pages without reload on my CMS System the database connection variable is lost ( get undefined ? ) and the page throw alot of errors related to the connection but when i load them with page reloads the error is gone and is thrown again when i load another page

main page

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
  include("includes/success.php");
}
if (isset($_GET['failure'])) {
  include("includes/failure.php");
}

?>

<?php include("phpscriptmain.php") ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/91c1c5c12c.js"></script>


  <title>Nibla Empower</title>


  <link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.9/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/finance.css'>

</head>

<body>
  <?php include "empower/parts/navbar.php" ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/materialCards.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stepper.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nucleon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/loader.css">
  <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
      <h1 class="h2">
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['src']))
          echo ucfirst($_GET['src']);
        else {
          echo "Dashboard";
        }
        ?>
      </h1>
      <?php
      if (!isset($_GET['src'])) {
        ?>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
            <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
            This week
          </button>
        </div>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
      $src = $_GET['src'];
    } else {
      $src = '';
    }
    ?>
    <div id="content">

      <?php
      switch ($src) {
        case 'main':
          include "empower/pages/main.php";
          break;
        case 'projects':
          include "empower/pages/projects.php";
          break;
        default:
          include "empower/pages/dashboard.php";
      }
      ?>

    </div>

    </div>
    <?php include "empower/parts/footer.php" ?>
```

navbar part

```php
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Nibla Studio</a>
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
    <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar" id="nav">

      <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-target="dashboard" class="nav-link <?php if (!isset($_GET['src'])) echo 'active'; ?>" href="finance.php">
              <span data-feather="home"></span>
              Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-target="main" class="nav-link <?php if (isset($_GET['src']) && strcmp($_GET['src'], "main") == 0) echo 'active'; ?>" href="?src=main">
              <span data-feather="grid"></span>
              Main <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a data-target="projects" class="nav-link <?php if (isset($_GET['src']) && strcmp($_GET['src'], "projects") == 0) echo 'active'; ?>" href="?src=projects">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
              Projects
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
              Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="users"></span>
              Customers
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
              Reports
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="layers"></span>
              Integrations
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
          <span>Saved reports</span>
          <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
            <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
          </a>
        </h6>
        <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
              Current month
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
              Last quarter
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
              Social engagement
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
              Year-end sale
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Set trigger and container variables
        var trigger = $('#nav div ul li a'),
          container = $('#content');

        // Fire on click
        trigger.on('click', function() {
          console.log("hiuu");
          // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
          var $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');

          // Load target page into container
          container.load("empower/pages/"+target + '.php');

          // Stop normal link behavior
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

a page that i am trying to load (path problem occurs here)

```php
<div class="content mt-3">
    <div class="animated fadeIn">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <strong class="card-title">Projects Table</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
                            $src = $_GET['src'];
                        } else {
                            $src = '';
                        }
                        switch ($src) {
                            case 'add_project':
                                include("includes/add_project.php");
                                break;
                            case 'edit':
                                include("includes/edit_project.php");
                                break;
                            case 'view_project':
                                include("includes/view_project.php");
                                break;
                            case 'view_project':
                                include("includes/view_project.php");
                                break;
                            default:
                                include("includes/view_all_projects.php");
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .animated -->
</div><!-- .content -->
```

another part of a another page i am trying to load (connection error occurs here)

```php
<?php
$session = session_id();
$time = time();
$time_out_in_sec = 60;
$time_out = $time - $time_out_in_sec;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE session = '$session'";
$online_users_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($online_users_query);
if ($count == 0) {
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `users_online` (`id`, `session`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, '$session', '$time');
");
} else {
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users_online SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'");
};

$online_users = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'");
$online_count = mysqli_num_rows($online_users);
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM projects";
$select_all_project = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$all_project_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_all_project);

$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_status = 'wip'";
$select_all_wip_project = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$wip_project_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_all_wip_project);


$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_status = 'on_hold'";
$select_all_onhold_project = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$onhold_project_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_all_onhold_project);

$query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_status = 'completed'";
$select_all_completed_project = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$completed_project_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_all_completed_project);

$query = "SELECT user_completed_projects FROM users WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'";
$select_all_completed_project = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$user_completed_project = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_completed_project);
?>
```

Comment: is $connection in a seperate file ? Is it included properly?

Comment: yes it's and it works for the first page once i load another page with AJAX the connection variable get undefined for no reason
sorry for the late reply i had family problem